# How do I loop and set multiple permission-set for a aws group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a loop which loop through my delacred local and set the permission sets for a aws group delclared in the locals. I am stuck and don´t really know how to do this in terraform. Here is my code.

```
    locals {

     dev = [{
            "groupname" = "role-aws-cloudops-developers",
            "permission_sets_cloudops" = local.aws_poweruser
            "permission_sets_cloudops" = local.aws_administrator    
            },
            {
             "groupname" = "role-aws-cloudops-viewers",
             "permission_sets_cloudops" = local.tf_viewer      
            }]  
    }




    module "sso_account_assignments_cloudops_sandbox" {
      source = "./modules/account-assignments"
      for_each                    = {for c, vm in local.dev: c => vm } 

      account_assignments = [

       {
        account            = var.accounts.SL.Sandbox
        permission_set_arn = "${each.value.permission_sets_cloudops}"
        principal_type     = "GROUP"
        principal_name     = "${each.value.groupname}"
          
       }
      
    ]



    }
```

#Output of terraform plan.

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
# module.sso_account_assignments_cloudops_sandbox["0"].aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.this["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "this" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + instance_arn       = "arn:aws:sso:::instance/ssoins-6804f84138f83ea2"
      + permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-6804f84138f83ea2/ps-80efa1b923c5aabb"
      + principal_id       = "9367118dab-515a198d-2cae-4b2f-81c6-d501509a80a8"
      + principal_type     = "GROUP"
      + target_id          = "276470352302"
      + target_type        = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
    }

  # module.sso_account_assignments_cloudops_sandbox["1"].aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment.this["0"] will be created
  + resource "aws_ssoadmin_account_assignment" "this" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + instance_arn       = "arn:aws:sso:::instance/ssoins-6804f84138f83ea2"
      + permission_set_arn = "arn:aws:sso:::permissionSet/ssoins-6804f84138f83ea2/ps-2983a7b1d2aa1d13"
      + principal_id       = "9367118dab-4a954498-4e6e-4ced-a5f0-83bd0720a888"
      + principal_type     = "GROUP"
      + target_id          = "276470352302"
      + target_type        = "AWS_ACCOUNT"
    }
Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

If I only have one permission-set it works but if I add 2 or more permission-sets for a group it still only set one permission set.. Any idea how I can change the code to gets all the permission-set I has declared and set it ?

Comment: "it failed" - is not specific! What does it mean? Any error messages? how to reproduce the issue?

Comment: It not failing it only set one permission-set under this block which I want to set 2 permission set.

{
        "groupname" = "role-aws-cloudops-developers",
        "permission_sets_cloudops" = local.aws_poweruser
        "permission_sets_cloudops" = local.aws_administrator    
        },

The code is going through terraform plan but not doing all the things I want. I think I am missing something but I can´t tell because I am pretty new to terraform.

Br

Comment: Please edit the question with new details. Code is not suited for comments.

Comment: Question edited and I also add the terraform plan output.

BR

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You get only one `permission_sets_cloudops` because you have **duplicate keys**, e.g.:

```
            {
            "groupname" = "role-aws-cloudops-developers",
            "permission_sets_cloudops" = "local.aws_poweruser"
            "permission_sets_cloudops" = "local.aws_administrator"    
            }
```

In the above, you have twice `permission_sets_cloudops` which will result in only the second one being used. All your keys in TF map **must be unique**. You need to **re-define** your data structures to ensure that, e.g. to use `list`:

```
           {
            "groupname" = "role-aws-cloudops-developers",
            "permission_sets_cloudops" = ["local.aws_poweruser", "local.aws_administrator"]
            }
```

This will obviously cascade down and will require you to modify the rest of your code.